# How to determine repeating pattern of bits in a single array

Tags: c, algorithm, binary, logic, logical-operators

So here is the problem, I'm building arrays of 128 bits, in C, to represent beat divisions, those divisions can be logically AND/OR/XOR'd against one another, so you can have results like below.  The problem I'm having is, how to determine when a pattern repeats, and what the start/end index of the first repeated section are, so that I can loop over just that section to prevent strange things happening when I reach the max (currently 128).

It seems like i'm going to need to increase the size to 256 or larger to account for situations where the more complex nested logic creates patterns that don't repeat for a while..  Looking for advice on how to detect the pattern algorithmic-ally within an array of bits.

```
2:              01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
3:              00100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100
3 OR  2:        01110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101110101
3 AND 2:        00000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100
3 XOR 2:        01110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001110001
                   ||    ||    ||    ||    || ...
5:              00001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000
5 OR (3 XOR 2): 01111001110001110001110011110101111001110001110001110011110101111001110001110001110011110101111001110001110001110011110101111001
                    ||                            ||                            ||                            ||                            ||
5 OR (3 OR 2):  01111101110101110101110111110101111101110101110101110111110101111101110101110101110111110101111101110101110101110111110101111101
                     ||                            ||                            ||                            ||
5:              00001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000010000100001000
6:              00000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100000100
5 OR 6:         00001100010100100101000110000100001100010100100101000110000100001100010100100101000110000100001100010100100101000110000100001100
                    ||                            ||                            ||                            ||                            ||
7:              00000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100
7 XOR (5 OR 6): 00001110010101100101100110010100000100010000100111000111000100101100000100101101000110000110001101010100000101010110001100001000
                shoot, 7 XOR (5 OR 6) doesn't repeat within 128 bits..
8:              00000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001
16:             00000000000000010000000000000001000000000000000100000000000000010000000000000001000000000000000100000000000000010000000000000001
```

to provide a little more context, this is for a logical clock divider that i've written for a musical module (https://llllllll.co/t/chrono-sage-meadowphysics-logical-clock-divider-v1-2-5/27182) and the issue I'm trying to solve is the ability to have these logical/nested logic combinations of beat divisions line up so there is no stutter when a pattern wraps around.

Comment: What is your criteria for identifying a repeating pattern?

Comment: Since these are created via logical operations, I would say the criteria is that the pattern is detected at least twice, initial and second repeat would confirm that the first pattern could provide the start/end indexes from which I could get length and initial offset. (offset because an unknown number of initial bits would not likely be a part of the repeated pattern).  The lines above mark where a pattern starts/ends.

Comment: So "1001" would be a repeating pattern in "111100110011001111111" ?  In fact, any string *x* would be considered a repeating pattern if *xxx* appears?

Comment: Unless I'm making a mistake (which is possible), it seems like for any combination of M and N bits, either M*N or the first positive integer that can be evenly divided by both M and N should give you a number of bits that's guaranteed to fit the repetition evenly, e.g. 210 bits for '7 XOR (5 OR 6)'. (The actual repetition may of course be shorter than that.) I don't know exactly what the goals and constraints are, but maybe that could be leveraged in some way.

Comment: Good point, thanks for your brain cycles! Additional parameters would be that that pattern would need to repeat until the end of the array but allow for part of the pattern to be truncated near the end of the array.. I'm wondering if maybe just trying to pre-compute all variations of logic/divisions might be a better approach. But there are a ton of variations. .. I've added a little more context to the message above.

Comment: Oh wow @scg, I'm going to test this out you may be right! If thats the case, that leaves the question, how to determine the initial offset so everything lines up.

Comment: Yikes, I think I may need to re-think the depth of nesting I'm allowing, creating patterns that don't repeat for 200+ or 2000+ bits seems not terribly musical anyway..

Comment: I think you need to start from the longest possible repeating pattern and check from there on down to the shortest, otherwise you may mistake a short repetition for the pattern while the actual pattern is longer (e.g., 1010110010101100 has two repetions of 10 but the pattern is 10101100). So first check if the second half is equal to the first. If it is, recursively continue halving to find the minimal length. If not, the pattern is either offset or truncated...

Comment: The repeating pattern should be no longer than the least common multiple of M and N, but it could be shorter than that, depending on the logical operation (e.g. repeating 01 OR repeating 0001 will produce repeating 01, but repeating 01 AND repeating 0001 will produce repeating 0001).

Answer (score 0):

Ian Abbott commented that the "repeating pattern should be no longer than the least common multiple of M and N" (M and N being the two [metres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(music)), I assume, although you've shown examples combining more than two). In fact, the naive combination of more than one metre is *exactly* a repeating pattern of length equal to their [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

But it looks like you are making additional, arbitrary choices, indicated by the lines in the examples, about where you'd like the "downbeat." On the face of it, without more clarification, we would be hard pressed to tell a computer what these criteria are. What are you thinking about (or better yet, *hearing*) that advises you to place the downbeats where you did, rather than at the start in the examples? Or is the issue that we don't have access to the original metres that were combined?

```
3/4 x . x|x . x|x . x|x . x
4/4 x . x x|x . x x|x . x x
(lcm = 12)
```